# Getting "pywintypes.com_error: 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed',.. " when creating PDF from docx

Tags: python, python-docx

While using **docx2pdf library** in **Python**, I am getting lots of errors.  I am unable to understand the example code. Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong with this code?

**Errors -**

```
    G:\xampp\htdocs\Dashboard\impact-angular\src>C:/Users/Utsav/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/Utsav/Desktop/Testing/test.py
  0%|                                                                                                                    | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Utsav/Desktop/Testing/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    convert("helloWorld.docx", "C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/helloWorld.pdf")
  File "C:\Users\Utsav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 106, in convert
    return windows(paths, keep_active)
  File "C:\Users\Utsav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 33, in windows
    doc.SaveAs(str(pdf_filepath), FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
  File "<COMObject Open>", line 5, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)
  0%|                                                                                                                    | 0/1 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
```

**Here's My Code**

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("helloWorld.docx", "C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/helloWorld.pdf")
```

Comment: hello can you show the error message

Comment: i added error also please check once @JasperNicholMFabella

Comment: @OcasoProtal please check

Comment: What happens when you give the full path for your docx, e.g. `convert("C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/helloWorld.docx", "C:/Users/Desktop/Testing/helloWorld.pdf")`? Assuming that your docx is in the same dir as your target pdf.